# Update huge record in vertica from impala

Tags: impala, vertica, bigdata, database

I have table A in vertica having 50 columns and in impala table B having 20 columns. Table A having date wise millions of records and want to update that records from impala once in a day for particular day. As using java i am updating 1000 batch through collection for 1 miliion record but takes more time, sometimes day. 
I have also tried to create new table copy of A for particular day and update into that and again reinsert all records to A. But no performance effect.

What could be the best approach for same so that i can do same task in less time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create table B in Vertica with 20 columns, like in impala.

Build a Java program that connects both to impala and Vertica. In that program, bulk read `SELECT * FROM impala.B` into arrays in memory, and use that same memory as host variables for the target statement `INSERT /*+DIRECT */ INTO vertica.B VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`.

Create (or keep) a staging table `stg_A` with the same structure and the same primary key (ideally one column), as the 50-col table A.

Truncate staging table, then `INSERT /*+DIRECT */ INTO stg_A SELECT B.*, A.col21,A.col22 .... A.col50 FROM B JOIN A ON stg_A.id=A.id` (if `id`is the primary key). This makes sure the 20 columns come from impala, and the rest comes from the target.

Finally, run an optimised merge:

```
MERGE /*+DIRECT*/
INTO A t
USING stg_A s
 ON s.id         = t.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  id    = s.id
, col02 = s.col02
, col03 = s.col03
, col04 = s.col04
, col05 = s.col05
[...]    
    , col50 = s.col50
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (
  s.s.id
, s.s.col02
, s.s.col03
, s.s.col04
, s.s.col05
, s.[...]
, s.s.col50
);
```

You will see that your merge is an optimised merge when the explain plan has a complete access path for INSERT and a complete access path for DELETE, and no access path for MERGE.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have tried another way like select * from impala and create table in vertica temp with same columns of above select* and insert all values into temp. Then update vertica B with comparing temp with join on similar keys and date condition single query. Just checking performance now..

Comment: Its working fine now... UPDATE A ts
   SET column1=t.column1
   FROM temp t
   WHERE ts.column2=t.column2 AND ts.column3=t.column3 and date(ts.column4)='2017-02-08';